# Is there an API for BIM360 Submittals?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I see endpoints for RFIs, Issues, and Check Lists but no submittals.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/

Does anyone know if submittals are these available via the API?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/introduction:

> Note that we do not currently support markups and submittals. In the near future we will be supporting more BIM 360 APIs - stay tuned!