# Does Forge support Submittals endpoints

Tags: autodesk-forge

I hope you are safe and doing well.
I’m working on a RESTFul client that reads info from the BIM360 API and couldn’t find any specification to retrieve Submittals.
Searching on your Knowledge base, I found the following answer from 2018:
autodesk forge - Is there an API for BIM360 Submittals? - Stack Overflow

Have you implemented the endpoint for submittals yet?
Thanks,

Henrique

Comment: The question looks to be a follow-up on another question. It would be better if it is added as a comment on that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598879/is-there-an-api-for-bim360-submittals) for better reach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, not yet :-( I will find the ID for a wish and add your name.